# how to split the string and store it in array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have tried the following example but it gives following out put
`output[]`. I have pass the string "1.0" to function `calculatePayout()` and want to store the 1 in `s[0]` and 0 in `s[1]`

```
import java.util.Arrays;


    public class aps {

        public void calculatePayout(String amount)
        {
            String[] s = amount.split(".");
            System.out.println("output"+Arrays.toString(s));
        }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new aps().calculatePayout("1.0");
    }
    }
```

Comment: There is a method in `String` class to do it.  Read the documentation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Method `split()` accepts regular expression. Character `.` in regular expressions means "everything". To split your string with `.` you have to escape it, i.e. `split("\\.")`. The second back slash is needed because the first one escapes dot for regular expression, the second escapes back slash for java compiler.

Comment: I would tend more towards saying "anything" rather than "everything".

Answer (score 4):

Try escaping the dot:

```
String[] s = amount.split("\\.");
```

As dot is "Any character" in [regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum).

Answer (score 3):

Try  `amount.split("\\.")`

[Split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method uses a regex so you need to use the correct syntax and escape the dot.

Answer (score 1):

`.` is a **metacharcter** or special character in regex world. `String#split(regex)` expects regex as parameter, you either have to escape it with backslash or use character class in-order to treat it as a normal character

Either `amount.split("\\.");` or `amount.split("[.]");`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
amount.split("\\.")
```

split method accepts a [regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)